# How to Navigate one view to other view

Tags: iphone, ios4, navigation, uibutton, subview

I used button action to to pop sub view sing below code;

```
- (IBAction)pickerUpBtn:(id)sender {

    PickerPopUpController *screen = [[PickerPopUpController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PickerPopUpController" bundle:Nil];
    [self.view addSubview:screen.view];
    [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
}
```

after i need to go previous window; So i used another button action for it and add bellow code inside action

```
PickerViewController *screen = [[PickerViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PickerViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:screen animated:YES];
```

But It does not navigate to previous view . How could i do it ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put only that single code in the Button action..No need of making object of parentViewController.

ie,

```
-(IBAction)btnaction:(id)sender{

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working.
when I navigate to previous view, how can I pass one of the text value to other. I have some test value to my second view. when I switched to previous view then I need to print on that text value to label. how can I do it??

Comment: how?? after i coming back to my previous view i need to print a value to lable.
I can print it on label...
 afterSelectView.category.text = label.text;

but I need to print that value on my first view. (Im getting that value from second view and Need to print on first view.) how could I do this?

Comment: You can Use NsuserDefaults as follows for eg:NSString *savedText=textLabel.text;[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:savedText forKey:@"sometext"]; and then retrieve it in the parentView as follows: NSString *retrievedText=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"sometext"]; You can get the value you stored in the previous view in "retrievedText".

Answer (score 3):

to go back,
do

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Comment: Thank for your help. Can you please describe what is happen of it. 
I mean "dismissModalViewControllerAnimated".

Comment: please check out http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:

Comment: when I navigate to previous view, how can I pass one of the text value to other. I have some test value to my second view. when I switched to second view. i need to print on that text value to label. how can I do it??

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `cancel` and `done` for your ViewController which is present modely to come back to parent view Controller.

After implementing  the `Cancel`  button, you have to dismiss your viewcontroller in the **action** function of `Cancel` button using the `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` function

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you Jhaliya. when I navigate to previous view, how can I pass one of the text value to other. I have some test value to my second view. when I switched to second view. i need to print on that text value to label. how can I do it??

Answer (score 0):

For push view controller, you can do like below,

```
 PickerViewController *screen = [[PickerViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PickerViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:screen animated:YES];
```

Then for go back, you have to add one button in "Screen" view controller and it's click event you have to write below code,

```
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Hope, it would be helpful.

Let me know in case of any difficulty.

---

If you are using the method "presentmodelviewcontroller" then you have to write below line in button click.

```
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you.when I navigate to previous view, how can I pass one of the text value to other. I have some test value to my second view. when I switched to second view. i need to print on that text value to label. how can I do it??

Comment: You can create one method like -(void)getTextValue:(NSString *)strStringValue;    Then you can simply call that method from first view controller by this way: [screen getTextValue:@"Your text"]; So, you will get the value to the next controller.